# Atlas - How to set in rows from table linked to polygonlayer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have polygonlayer and a textlayer. The polygons have unique ID´numbers. The textfile also have unique ID-numbers (and therefore possible to join together, yes), but it contains several rows with the same ID-number. In Print Composers Atlas it´s no problem to make an output print for each polygon by the ID, but I want to show the rows in the table/text-document as well. I can´t figure out if I´ll have to join the text-document by the polygonlayer or try with the Expression filter?  For Q-GIS 2.0. This i s what I want as output for each output:[image]

Comment: The text-table is a sql on another layer of polygons within the above layer and its polygons.

Comment: Not possible to solve?

Comment: Found solution. Text got a polygon onto it and then attribute table are put in the print composer.